# Static web hosting on Dropbox — index.html

Tags: dropbox, blog, hosting

To host my blog, I added a file called index.html to `Public/blog` in Dropbox.

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/01234567/blog/index.html
```

However, I get a 404 message if I try to access without the index.html. Is there anyway to get it to work? Possibly with the `/` at the end.

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/01234567/blog
```

See [this](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/host-websites-with-dropbox) article as well. The site works, I just want to take off the index.html at the end.

Comment: You can use GitHub pages for that:
https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) is intended for file sharing, not really web hosting and will even limit the traffic to your site if it gets too much traffic. If you are just trying to host some kind of blog I suggest using a blogging platform such as [WordPress](https://wordpress.com/) that allows you to create a free blog.

Answer (score 4):

The `index.html` redirect from `/` is resolved by the web server. Given that Dropbox doesn’t offer a *web hosting* service, but a *file hosting* service, I doubt you’ll be able to make it work the way you want.